# ReactNative nested render functions. Question regarding `this` between objects and functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, this, javascript-objects

Here is my confusion:

```
     constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  hookNav(){
    console.log("work");
  }

  renderItem({ item, index }) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{ margin: 9 }} onPress={this.hookNav}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            minWidth: 170,
            maxWidth: 223,
            height: 280,
            maxHeight: 280,
            borderRadius: 10,
          }}
        >
          <ImageBackground
            source={{
              uri: "https://picsum.photos/170/223",
            }}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 10 }}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                color: "white",
                position: "absolute",
                bottom: 20,
                right: 10,
                fontWeight: "bold",
                textShadowColor: "black",
                textShadowOffset: { width: -1, height: 1 },
                textShadowRadius: 10,
              }}
            >
              Topic
            </Text>
          </ImageBackground>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View style={{ marginBottom: 80, backgroundColor: "white" }}>
        <Header
          centerComponent={{ text: "test", style: { color: "orange" } }}
          rightComponent={{ icon: "add", color: "orange" }}
        />
        <FlatList
          numColumns={2}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0}
          onEndReached={({ distanceFromEnd }) => {
            console.debug("on end reached ", distanceFromEnd);
          }}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
          data={[
            { key: "a" },
            { key: "b" },
            { key: "c" },
            { key: "d" },
            { key: "e" },
            { key: "f" },
          ]}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          ListHeaderComponent={
            <Text
              style={{ padding: 10, fontWeight: "bold" }}
            >
              Your Topics
            </Text>
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

in this code above, when navigating to this page an error is immediately thrown that `this.hookNav` is undefined.

However, when I put the `hookNav` function inside of a state object, like so

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    state = {
      hookNav : function() {
       console.log("work please");
      }
    }
  }
```

and in `onPress` inside of `renderItem`

```
const { hookNav} = this.state;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{ margin: 9 }} onPress={hookNav}>
```

This works as intended.

It is my understanding that `render` already has access to the component’s `state` via `this`. If `renderItem` can access the `state` object, through `this`, why can it not access `this.hookNav()` directly? Why does the function need to be encapsulated in an object for this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the value of `this` inside any Javascript function depends on how that function was called.

In your non-working example, `this.hookNav` is inside of the `renderItem` method. So it will adopt the `this` of that method - which, as I just said, depends on how it is called. Further inspecting your code shows that the `renderItem` method isn't called directly by your component but passed as a prop (called `renderItem`) of the `FlatList` component. Now I don't know how that component is implemented (I've never used React Native), but almost certainly it calls that function at some point - and when it does, it can't be in the context of your component. This is because `FlatList` can't possibly know where that function prop is coming from, and when it calls it, it will be treated as an "ordinary" function, not in the context of any particular object. So its `this` context won't be your component instance, as intended, but will simply be the global object - which doesn't have any `hookNav` method.

This problem doesn't happen in your second example because you simply access the function as part of `this.state` - there is no passing of a method, like the `renderItem` in the previous example, which depends on an internal `this` reference. Note that this won't be the case if your `hookNav` refers to `this` inside it.

Such problems with `this` context are very common in React, but fortunately there are two general solutions which will always fix this:

1. Bind methods in your component's constructor. If the constructor, in the first example, includes the statement `this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);`, then it would work fine. (Note that this is recommended in the official React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).) It's the "best" solution technically (performance is slightly better than in the other option) - but does involve quite a bit of boilerplate if you have lots of methods which need such binding.
2. Use arrow functions to define the methods instead. Instead of `renderItem({ item, index }) {...}`, write it as `renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {...}`. This works because arrow functions adopt the `this` of their lexical scope, which will be the class itself - so in other words `this` will always refer to the component instance, as you almost always want.

Don't worry if this is confusing - the behaviour of the `this` keyword in JS is a common stumbling block for beginners to JS, and often enough for those more experienced too. There are a number of good explanations online which demystify it, of which I can especially recommend [this one](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md).

Comment: Wonderful answer, thank you.
I tried `this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);` previously, although I used 
`this.hookNav = this.hookNav.bind(this);` instead. So given what you explained I assume this did not work because it matters about the context in which the function is called. `renderItem`, or `flatList` is the thing calling `hookNav` so binding `hookNav's` `this` is inconsequential?

Comment: `hookNav` doesn't refer to `this` at all, so whether you bind it or not is inconsequential. And even if you change it so that it does (since the current version is clearly just a test), it might not be needed - if you call it directly as `this.hookNav()` from within another method then it should work fine. This problem typically comes when you reference a method as an event handler or as a prop in a child component, without calling it directly - which is what you were doing with `renderItem`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind the method in to `this` of your class. One way to do so will be like below.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
}
```